# Moving subfolders that match a specific pattern using zsh

Tags: for-loop, zsh

I've got a lot of files following the pattern

```
/folder1/abcd-hi
/folder2/randomletters-hi
/folder3/moreletters-hi
```

where I'm trying to move every specific folder with the suffix "-hi" to a new directory. I'm kind of new to zsh scripting and can't really figure this one out.

So far I've tried this to no success:

```
for Folder in */
do
mv "$Folder/*-hi" newfolder
done
```

Automating this would save me a lot of time.

Comment: Stack Exchange site *[Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tour)* is a script writing service site. They will be more than happy to take it.

Comment: `mv -v */*-hi newfolder` should work for what you've described.

Comment: Adding to the idea by _Gairfowl_: I would also consider using the `-i` option.